# React: Ref DOM Elements/Nodes are printing different information from the actual Ref DOM?

Tags: reactjs, dom, use-effect, react-calendar

I'm using React Calendar https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar and I'm using their ref prop to manipulate the date buttons so that I can add custom functionality straight to the calendar DOM (only real way to do this I think since their props are limited. if you guys know a better way tho please let me know so I can stop using this method! btw I know tileClassName to add CSS exists but I want to have some hovering Features which I can't seem to wrap my head around for putting that in tileClassName). The react calendar ref is a reference to the overall calendar div and not a React component :( .

**Calendar.jsx in react-calendar/src/YearView/Calendar.jsx**

```
return (
      <div
        className={mergeClassNames(
          baseClassName,
          selectRange && valueArray.length === 1 && `${baseClassName}--selectRange`,
          showDoubleView && `${baseClassName}--doubleView`,
          className,
        )}
        ref={inputRef}
      >
        {this.renderNavigation()}
        <div
          className={`${baseClassName}__viewContainer`}
          onBlur={selectRange ? onMouseLeave : null}
          onMouseLeave={selectRange ? onMouseLeave : null}
        >
          {this.renderContent()}
          {showDoubleView && this.renderContent(true)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Now in my custom calendar js, on every useEffect, I have it set up so that the click next navigation button of the current Ref changes a month State that is a dependent of useEffect so that useEffect can be re-triggered again.
[image]

```
const MainCalendar = () => {
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(0)
  const ref = React.useRef()

useEffect(() => {
    // arrows in ref Change State
    ref.current.getElementsByClassName('react-calendar__navigation__arrow react-calendar__navigation__next-button')[0].onclick = () => {
      setMonth(month + 1)
      return
    }
    console.log(ref.current)
    console.log(ref.current.getElementsByClassName('react-calendar__navigation__label')[0].children[0].textContent)
}, [month])

return(
     <Calendar
          inputRef={ref}/>)
}
```

Now, when I click this arrow button circled red, the re-trigger indeed happens as the console logged the two items again, but if you check my useEffect function, I am printing both the ref.Current and an ELEMENT in that ref.Current. This element that I chose is the Title Month/Year (ex: July 2021 in the image above). Now, the console is printing the current ref DOM correctly  (the first console print) with the new August 2021 date (since the navigation button moves up a month), but when I access the ref DOM using getElementByClassName, it seems to be printing the previous Ref element (second console print) and not the current Ref Element title that I need. (ex: printing July 2021 when it should be August 2021)

[image]

How can I fix it so that the Ref elements being accessed in useEffect is the most current information (basically the information from the logged ref.current)? It doesn't seem to be the case even though, printing ref.current shows August 2021. I need it to be up to date exactly once useEffect retriggers so that I can set up conditionals based on the current Title being presented, but I can't do that right now because of this dilemma. What's the best way to have those ref elements up to date? Thanks

Comment: So you want to add custom code when the month gets changed?

Comment: @MeeraDatey I want to have access the DOM elements when the months change. It doesn't seem to be giving me the latest update of the DOM elements though when I do useEffect and try to access those elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

```
async function waitForDate(i) {
    function dateChanged() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
          resolve()
        })
        var config = { characterData: true, attributes: false, childList: false, subtree: true }

        observer.observe(ref.current.getElementsByClassName('react-calendar__navigation__label')[0].children[0], config)
      })
    }

    await dateChanged()

    setMonth(month + i)
  }
```

I called this waitForDate function inside the onclick method of useEffect.

I created an async function that observes and waits for the ref element to change the title element. Once that is triggered, I then useEffect to reRender the entire thing.

It seems that my previous solution didn't take into account that the current Ref might still be stale once the navigation button is clicked and the retriggering of useEffect happens. So I must first wait and confirm that it has changed with this function I used.

Comment: Life saver! Many thx